# Converting React Functional Component to Hook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

While trying to learn full stack development I was trying out this tutorial ( https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/ )  on a React-Express-Node basic app.  However, it was written using functional components instead of hooks.  I'm trying to convert this section to a hook:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { apiResponse: "" };
}

callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.callAPI();
}
```

with this in the render section:

```
<p className="App-intro">;{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
```

I tried this:

```
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState();
   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchApiResponse = async () => {
       const result = await (
         'http://localhost:9000/testAPI'
       );
       setApiResponse(result);
       console.log("apiResponse " + apiResponse);
     };
     fetchApiResponse();
   });
```

but the console.log of the apiResponse always shows as undefined.  I know I must be doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Not an answer but just for helpfulness: a hook gets used *inside* a functional component. You're referring to a **class** component that you want converted to a **functional** component. A hook is the stuff actually imported from react like `useState` or `useEffect`, not a type of component.

Comment: `setApiResponse` is async, which is why you won't immediately see the change after setting the value. Also, why are you using await on setting the value of a string to a static value?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't far off in your attempt.

There are two problems:

**Problem 1.**

In order to get the same effect as `componentWillMount` (side note - this is a deprecated method, use `componentDidMount` or the `constructor`) you need to tell the `useEffect` to only run once on mount. To do this you give it an empty array of dependencies.

```js
useEffect(() => {
// do stuff
}, []); // empty array as second argument
```

By not giving a second argument, the effect will run every single render.

**Problem 2.**

State updates are asynchronous. This means you cannot console log `apiResponse` immediately after updating it and expect it to contain the new value.

To get around this, just console.log inside the function body outside of the hook.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState();
  
   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchApiResponse = () => {
       const result = 'test';
       setApiResponse(result);
       // Will not be updated
       console.log("wrong: apiResponse ", apiResponse);
     }
     fetchApiResponse();
   }, []);
   
   // Will be updated
   console.log("right: apiResponse ", apiResponse);
   
   return <span />
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```